# create a loop to get samples in grouped data which meet a condition

Tags: r, loops, sample

I have a dataframe where data are grouped by ID. I need to know how many cells are the 10% of each group in order to select this number in a sample, but this sample should select the cells which EP is 1.

I've tried to do a nested For loop: one For to know the quantity of cells which are the 10% for each group and the bigger one to sample this number meeting the condition EP==1

```
x <- data.frame("ID"=rep(1:2, each=10),"EP" = rep(0:1, times=10))
x
   ID EP
1   1  0
2   1  1
3   1  0
4   1  1
5   1  0
6   1  1
7   1  0
8   1  1
9   1  0
10  1  1
11  2  0
12  2  1
13  2  0
14  2  1
15  2  0
16  2  1
17  2  0
18  2  1
19  2  0
20  2  1

for(j in 1:1000){
  for (i in 1:nrow(x)){
    d <- x[x$ID==i,]
    npix <- 10*nrow(d)/100
  }
  r <- sample(d[d$EP==1,],npix)
  print(r)
}
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
.
.
.
until 1000
```

I would want to get this dataframe, where each sample is in a new column in x, and the cell sampled has "1":

```
   ID EP s1 s2....s1000
1   1  0 0  0 ....
2   1  1 0  1
3   1  0 0  0
4   1  1 0  0
5   1  0 0  0
6   1  1 0  0
7   1  0 0  0
8   1  1 0  0
9   1  0 0  0
10  1  1 1  0
11  2  0 0  0
12  2  1 0  0
13  2  0 0  0
14  2  1 0  1
15  2  0 0  0
16  2  1 0  0
17  2  0 0  0
18  2  1 1  0
19  2  0 0  0
20  2  1 0  0
```

see that each 1 in S1 and s2 are the sampled cells and correspond to 10% of cells in each group (1, 2) which meet the condition EP==1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write a function which gives us 1's which are 10% for each `ID` and place it where `EP = 1`.

```
library(dplyr)
 rep_func <- function() {
   x %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(s1 = 0,
           s1 = replace(s1, sample(which(EP == 1), floor(0.1 * n())), 1)) %>%
    pull(s1)
}
```

then use `replicate` to repeat it for `n` times

```
n <- 5
x[paste0("s", seq_len(n))] <- replicate(n, rep_func())

x
#   ID EP s1 s2 s3 s4 s5
#1   1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#2   1  1  0  0  0  0  0
#3   1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#4   1  1  0  0  0  0  0
#5   1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#6   1  1  1  0  0  1  0
#7   1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#8   1  1  0  1  0  0  0
#9   1  0  0  0  0  0  0
#10  1  1  0  0  1  0  1
#11  2  0  0  0  0  0  0
#12  2  1  0  0  1  0  0
#13  2  0  0  0  0  0  0
#14  2  1  1  1  0  0  0
#15  2  0  0  0  0  0  0
#16  2  1  0  0  0  0  1
#17  2  0  0  0  0  0  0
#18  2  1  0  0  0  1  0
#19  2  0  0  0  0  0  0
#20  2  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: where can I see details of the floor argument? it's not the replace{base}, is it?

Comment: @LuisaAnaya `floor` is in base R only. `?floor` . You can also use `?ceiling`, `floor` and `ceiling` gives lower and upper bound of a numeric.

Comment: I think in that argument is something wrong, cause I run your code and dont get your answer. instead I get cols all with zeros

Comment: @LuisaAnaya strange it works for me though, Can you change the line to `s1 = replace(s1, sample(which(EP == 1), 0.1 * n()), 1)) %>%` removing the `floor` argument ? Did you run it on your sample data, did it work there?

Comment: fixed up!! I kept floor and used mean, and it works!!! I think the problem was because dplyr was masked by plyr, so the correct line in my case (because I called both packages plyr and dplyr) is:
dplyr::mutate(s1 = 0, s1 = replace(s1, sample(which(EP == 1), floor(0.1 * n())), 1))

Comment: @LuisaAnaya ohh..yes. that might be an issue. As I don't have `plyr` loaded it was working for me. Glad it worked finally for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer, very clever the way you solve

Comment: If I have another issue to take into account, how can you solve it?. I want to select the 10% of the cells per group which meet EP==1 (still nothing different) but now those selected cells should content all cells which meet EX==1 (another column with 0 and 1s). I think should be a way to change the arguments of `floor` to tell: make a sample with 10% of each group which include all cells EX==1 and complete this percentage with EP==1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56983394/create-samples-whit-function-in-grouped-data-which-meet-a-condition

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
set.seed(1231)
x <- data.frame("ID"=rep(1:2, each=10),"EP" = rep(0:1, times=10))

library(tidyverse)
x %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(index= ifelse(EP==1, 1:n(),0)) %>% 
  mutate(s1 = ifelse(index %in% sample(index[index!=0], n()*0.1), 1, 0)) %>% 
  mutate(s2 = ifelse(index %in% sample(index[index!=0], n()*0.1), 1, 0))
# A tibble: 20 x 5
# Groups:   ID [2]
      ID    EP index    s1    s2
   <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     0     0     0     0
 2     1     1     2     0     0
 3     1     0     0     0     0
 4     1     1     4     0     0
 5     1     0     0     0     0
 6     1     1     6     1     1
 7     1     0     0     0     0
 8     1     1     8     0     0
 9     1     0     0     0     0
10     1     1    10     0     0
11     2     0     0     0     0
12     2     1     2     0     0
13     2     0     0     0     0
14     2     1     4     0     1
15     2     0     0     0     0
16     2     1     6     0     0
17     2     0     0     0     0
18     2     1     8     0     0
19     2     0     0     0     0
20     2     1    10     1     0
```