# create samples with function in grouped data which meet a condition

Tags: r

I want to create samples which are 10% of the cells of each group but in this sample should be included the cells which meet EX==1, and complete the sample (if necessary) with those that meet PL==1. I need to repeat it many times (1000)

I have used a function to create the sample and paste it in the df. I think to get what I want, the arguments of `floor` would be changed.

```
> rep_func <- function() {
+ x %>%
+   group_by(ID) %>%
+     dplyr::mutate(s1 = 0,
+          s1 = replace(s1, sample(which(PL == 1), floor(0.1 * n())), 1)) %>%
+   pull(s1)
+ }
> n <- 2
> x[paste0("s", seq_len(n))] <- replicate(n, rep_func())
> x
   ID PL EX s1 s2
1   1  0  1  0  0
2   1  1  0  0  0
3   1  0  0  0  0
4   1  1  0  0  0
5   1  0  0  0  0
6   1  1  0  0  0
7   1  0  0  0  0
8   1  1  0  0  0
9   1  0  0  0  0
10  1  1  0  1  1
11  1  0  0  0  0
12  1  1  0  0  1
13  1  0  0  0  0
14  1  1  0  0  0
15  1  0  0  0  0
16  1  1  0  0  0
17  1  0  0  0  0
18  1  1  0  0  0
19  1  0  0  0  0
20  1  1  0  1  0
21  2  0  0  0  0
22  2  1  0  0  0
23  2  0  0  0  0
24  2  1  0  0  0
25  2  0  0  0  0
26  2  1  0  0  0
27  2  0  1  0  0
28  2  1  0  1  1
29  2  0  0  0  0
30  2  1  0  0  0
```

I need the numbers 1 in the samples be those cell which meet EX==1, but if is necessary to complete the sample and reach 10%, choose those cells which meet PL==1. So, in the example, the ID-Group 1 has a cell which meet EX==1 and it was not selected in the s1

Comment: So you want randomly 10% for each `ID`, and also set to `1` if `PL` or `EX` is `1`?

Comment: not exactly, I want prioritize EX over PL and random 10%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle this updated case, we create a new function called `replace_func` which would be called for each group (`ID`) and will prioritise the filling of `EX` values and if some values still remain to complete 10% of the group uses `PL` values to fill it.

```
library(dplyr)

replace_func <- function(EX, PL) {
    s = integer(length(EX))
    n <- floor(0.1 * length(EX))
    ex1 <- EX == 1
    if (sum(ex1) > n)
       return(replace(s, sample(which(ex1), n), 1))
    else {
       s1 <- replace(s, ex1, 1)
       return(replace(s1, sample(which(PL == 1), n - sum(ex1)), 1))
  }
}

rep_func <- function() {
    x %>%
     group_by(ID) %>%
     mutate(s1 = replace_func(EX, PL)) %>%
     pull(s1)
}
```

and then use `replicate` to get `n` number of columns

```
n <- 2
x[paste0("s", seq_len(n))] <- replicate(5, rep_func())

x
#   ID PL EX s1 s2
#1   1  0  1  1  1
#2   1  1  0  0  0
#3   1  0  0  0  0
#4   1  1  0  0  0
#5   1  0  0  0  0
#6   1  1  0  0  0
#7   1  0  0  0  0
#8   1  1  0  0  0
#9   1  0  0  0  0
#10  1  1  0  1  0
#11  1  0  0  0  0
#12  1  1  0  0  1
#13  1  0  0  0  0
#14  1  1  0  0  0
#15  1  0  0  0  0
#16  1  1  0  0  0
#17  1  0  0  0  0
#18  1  1  0  0  0
#19  1  0  0  0  0
#20  1  1  0  0  0
#21  2  0  0  0  0
#22  2  1  0  0  0
#23  2  0  0  0  0
#24  2  1  0  0  0
#25  2  0  0  0  0
#26  2  1  0  0  0
#27  2  0  1  1  1
#28  2  1  0  0  0
#29  2  0  0  0  0
#30  2  1  0  0  0
```